# Google Sheets Formula - Get Total from filtered dates per row (undefined number of columns)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have this data in Google Sheets where in I need to get the total of the filtered data columns per row. The date columns are not fixed (may increase over time, I already know how to handle this undefined number of columns). What my current challenge encountered is how can I efficiently get a summary of totals per user based on filtered date columns.

**My data is like this:**

[image]

**My expected result is like this:**

[image]

**My current idea is this:**

[image]

Here is a sample spreadsheet for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dByPabStGQvh94TabKxwFeUyVaRFnkBCRf4ioTY5jM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a method to unpivot the data so you can work with it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
   IFERROR(
    SPLIT(
     FLATTEN(
      IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,A2:A&"|"&B1:G1&"|"&B2:G)),
     "|")),
   "select Col1, Sum(Col3)
    where
     Col2 >= "&DATE(2022,1,1)&" and
     Col2 <= "&DATE(2022,1,15)&"
    group by Col1
    label
     Col1 'Person',
     Sum(Col3) 'Total'"))
```

Basically, its creating an output of `User1|44557|8` -- it then FLATTENs it all and splits by the pipe, which gives you three clean columns.

Run that through a QUERY to SUM by the person between the dates and you get what you're after. If you wanted to use cell references for dates, simply replace the dates with the cell references.

To expand the table, change B1:G1 and B2:G2 to match the width of the range.